# .NET Core with OData XML File (.NET)

Tags: xml, .net-core, odata

I am trying to parse this XML file from an OData API in order to replicate the data model. I get an error that says

> Failed to Load Metadata

There are a lot of packages and maybe there is a conflict - all packages are listed below that I installed. Path is right to XML and it is valid.

```
using System;
using System.Xml; // Add this using statement for XmlReader
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm.Csdl;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm.Validation;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Load metadata XML file
        string xmlFilePath = "./response.xml" ;  // Update with your actual file path
        string xmlContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(xmlFilePath);

        // Parse metadata XML and get EdmModel
        IEdmModel edmModel;
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xmlContent)))
        {
            IEnumerable<EdmError> errors;
            if (CsdlReader.TryParse(reader, out edmModel, out errors))
            {
                if (!errors.Any())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Metadata loaded successfully.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Metadata loaded with errors:");
                    foreach (var error in errors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"  {error}");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to load metadata.");
            }
        }

        // Replicate data model from EdmModel
        // You can implement your own logic here to replicate the data model based on the parsed EdmModel
        // For example, you can access the EdmModel to get entity types, properties, and relationships, and use them to generate corresponding classes or data models in your application
        // You can use the EdmModel to build and execute OData queries and requests, or to implement OData services
    }
}
```

Here are the packages I have installed to do this.

```
Top-level Package                   Requested   Resolved

* Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData        8.1.1       8.1.1   
* Microsoft.OData.Core              7.15.0      7.15.0  
* Microsoft.OData.Edm               7.15.0      7.15.0  
* Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder      1.0.9       1.0.9   
* Microsoft.Spatial                 7.15.0      7.15.0
```

Path is right, XML is valid, there are shit ton of packages in OData and .NET Core. Maybe one is wrong?

Comment: The Meta Data serializes c# classes, sends serialized data in body of a HTTP connection, and then deserialize the the body back to c# classes.  The client and server needs to have same c# classes and same target version of Net/Core for code to run without errors.